# Github Actions to mirror and sync with AWS codecommit

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, github-actions, aws-codecommit

I am planning to Synchronize a repo in GitHub and to AWS codecommit. All the present code and future PR's merging to main, dev, and preprod should be in the AWS codecommit. I am referring to GitHub Actions and I see three different wiki/documentation. I am not sure which one to follow?

1.https://github.com/marketplace/actions/github-to-aws-codecommit-sync

2.https://github.com/marketplace/actions/mirroring-repository

3.https://github.com/marketplace/actions/automatic-repository-mirror

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one ([`actions/github-to-aws-codecommit-sync`](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/github-to-aws-codecommit-sync)) should be enough.

Its [script `entrypoint.sh`](https://github.com/tsgit18/sync-up-to-codecommit-action/blob/f8764bf63c636c16c98d55d2ebe44fff0e37e707/entrypoint.sh) does a:

```
git config --global credential.'https://git-codecommit.*.amazonaws.com'.helper '!aws codecommit credential-helper $@'
git remote add sync ${CodeCommitUrl}
git push sync --mirror
```

That should pull all branches, including PR branches (in [`refs/pull/` namespace](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/reviewing-changes-in-pull-requests/checking-out-pull-requests-locally#error-failed-to-push-some-refs=))

That action should be called on [merged PR](https://github.community/t/trigger-workflow-only-on-pull-request-merge/17359/19?u=vonc):

```yaml
name: OnMergedPR
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - "**"
      - "!main"

  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main
    types: [opened, synchronize, closed]

  workflow_dispatch: 

jobs:   
  build:
    if: (!(github.event.action == 'closed' && github.event.pull_request.merged != true))

...
```

Comment: would it also Synchronize all the future PRs merging to main, dev, and preprod branches?

Comment: It would, provided you configure your [GitHub action to trigger on merged PR](https://github.community/t/trigger-workflow-only-on-pull-request-merge/17359/19?u=vonc).

Comment: Thanks, one last question. I am not clear what `types` under `pull_request` does. I only want the GitHub action to trigger when the pr is merged to main or dev or preprod

Comment: @Eva Yes, you will need to experiment/tweak the YAML I copied in the answer to adapt to your case.